# Error API resolved without sending a response for /api/post, this may result in stalled requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, axios

I am a beginner in frontend path. I try to make post requests in order to upload a video  to sanity backend content in my post-saving page. It seems that I should use here a new Promise(resolve/reject). But when I apply it, it shows an error regarding await/async. Or I made sth wrong. Any ideas ?

> -> Terminal: API resolved without sending a response for /api/post, this may result in stalled requests. error - unhandledRejection:
> ClientError: Mutation(s) failed with 1 error(s)
>
> Fold Structure --> pages/api/post/index.ts

Many thanks in advance!

api/post/index.ts file

---

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

import { allPostsQuery } from '../../../utils/queries'; 
import { client } from '../../../utils/client';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) { 

if (req.method === 'GET') { const query = allPostsQuery();
    const data = await client.fetch(query);

    res.status(200).json(data);
} 
else if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const doc = req.body;

    client.create(doc).then(() => {
        res.status(201).json('video created');
    });
}
```

}

//method for saving post:

```
const handlePost = async () => { if (caption && videoAsset?._id && topic) {  

  setSavingPost(true);    
  const doc = {
            _type: 'post',
            caption,
            video: {
                _type: 'file',
                asset: {
                    _type: 'reference',
                    _ref: videoAsset?._id,
                },
            },
            userId: userProfile?._id,
            postedBy: {
                _type: 'postedBy',
                _ref: userProfile?._id,
            },
            topic,
        };

        await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/post', doc);

       router.push("/")
    }
};
```

Comment: Please add the full error message to the question

Comment: Full error message added to the question